# Mass of files and dlls in my project directory VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

so I have been learning C# and I seem to be doing fairly well. I do have one question though, I have a few manifest files, all the dlls, and stuff that resides in my bin/release folder. I was wondering if there was a way to have some kind of structure to the output from the release. like a dll folder for dll's. it just seems kind of odd to just have them all dumped there.

Comment: That's the normal method of working.  You can potentially do other organizational structures, but it will make your life much harder, as the assemblies won't be found if they're not there...

Comment: It is not impossible but it is *very* unwise.  You have to provide special config to help the CLR find the DLLs.  Which is another kind of untidy, DLL Hell is nothing fun to ever have to deal with.  Don't do it.

Comment: The bin / release folders are usually not a places in which you work much, so this usually doesn't matter at all. If you always have to search for the same file (e.g. the exe to start it) create shortcuts or batch file in your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

The system typically retrieves `.dll`s from various places (like the global assembly cache  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache), not just the current folder. Don't worry too much about where the actual files are. If you manage your solution well you will have the structure where you need it (i.e. where you actually work) and the computer will be able to find what it needs easily enough.

What you can do though, if you'd like, is to share common projects between different solutions by adding them as link in Visual Studio (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100).aspx). That way you can structure you code in a more manageable way, without unnecessary duplication.